# How to implement service in a class in rospy with no args?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to implement a service on Kinetic (no args, two return values) but I am getting the error:

```
service [/classify_container] responded with an error: error processing request: classify_container() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Classification.srv

```
---
string class_name
float32 confidence
```

The Service

```
from pytorch_ros.srv import Classification

class PytorchNode(object):
    def __init__(self):
        classification_service = rospy.Service('classify',
                                               Classification,
                                               self.classify_handle)
                                               
    def classify_handle(self):
        # do some stuff
        # to get the classification
        # .....
        
        # construct msg and return
        classification_msg = Classification()
        classification_msg.class_name = self.names[classification]
        classification_msg.confidence = confidence
  
        return classification_msg
```

The client

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  from __future__ import division
  from __future__ import print_function

  import rospy 
  from pytorch_ros.srv import Classification
 
  rospy.wait_for_service('classify_container')
  
  try:
      srv_classify_container = rospy.ServiceProxy('classify_container', Classification)
      classification = srv_classify_container()
      print(classification.class_name)
      print(classification.confidence)
  except rospy.ServiceException as e:
      print("Service call failed: %s" % e)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357883/how-to-implement-service-in-a-class-in-rospy-with-no-args?/) by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2020-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even if your service definition has no fields in the request portion, a request class is still created and your server callback must still adhere to the function signature required of the callback. The signature is described in the [API docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.impl.tcpros_service.Service-class.html). The function should take a request and return a response.

So your code could be roughly updated as:

```
from pytorch_ros.srv import Classification
from pytorch_ros.srv import ClassificationRequest
from pytorch_ros.srv import ClassificationResponse

class PytorchNode(object):
    def __init__(self):
        classification_service = rospy.Service('classify',
                                               Classification,
                                               self.classify_handle)

    def classify_handle(self, request):
        # do some stuff
        # to get the classification
        # .....

        # construct msg and return
        classification_response = ClassificationResponse()
        classification_response.class_name = self.names[classification]
        classification_response.confidence = confidence

        return classification_response
```

Note: This is very much what is presented in the [Writing a Simple Service and Client (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on 2020-07-24**:
thanks, this line `from pytorch_ros.srv import ClassificationRequest` appears to be redundant?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-07-27**:
Yes. If you aren't explicitly instantiating a request in the file implementing the server.